# Embedding video into code

Tags: html, video, video-embedding

I have been trying to do this 4ever now and can't figure it out. I can embed a video with quicktime but it is REALLY buggy right now with the latest release. Is there any other way to embed a video without using quicktime or windows player?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try HTML5 video tag like;

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

***[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_all)*** is a Live Demo.

You may have a look at **[Top 10 Ways to Embed Video into a Web Page](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/02/29/top-10-ways-to-embed-video-into-a-web-page/)** and **[4 New Ways to Embed Video](http://en.blog.wordpress.com/2007/02/05/4-new-ways-to-embed-video/)**

Answer (score 0):

Html5's video tag.  Of course, the browser has to support it, but this is the only other way to my knowledge, aside from Adobe's Flash Player:

```
<video width="200" height="200" controls="controls">
    <source src="some_movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    Video tag unsupported.
</video>
```

Good example: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/

Answer (score 0):

Using the "video" tag has its limits indeed. In example: you can't resize the video using the parameters in the tag, so you are limited to build a video that fits the container where you are going to place it. Otherwise the video will resize strictly observing the original aspect ratio.

For a more flexible website video player, you may wish to choose from a jQuery or other style video player of which I suggest you to take a look at the answers provided in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697556/best-html5-video-player of which, the accepted answer refers to Sublimevideo but the most voted answer (today) includes the next list:

> Check out these links:
>
> 1. [http://videojs.com/](http://videojs.com)
> 2. http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-html5
> 3. http://sublimevideo.net/
> 4. http://www.dailymotion.com/html5
> 5. http://www.html5video.org/kaltura-html5/
> 6. http://www.youtube.com/html5
> 7. http://vimeo.com/blog:268
> 8. http://flarevideo.com/
> 9. http://www.mediafront.org/project/osmplayer
> 10. http://darkonyx.web-anatomy.com

All these are easy to implement. Not as easy as simply writing a tag and filling the parameters but if you wish flexibility/customization many of these are a good choice.

Good luck!